# How to connect to a database (unknown host, no ip)

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi

I have a database hosted by one.com with these settings:

> PhpMyAdmin: https://dbadmin.one.com
>
> Host: axelerate.be.mysql
>
> Database: axelerate_be
>
> Username: axelerate_be
>
> Password: *********

I want to make connection with this database by using a php file runned by the LXTerminal of the raspberry pi. When i try to make connection i get this error (host unknown):

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Host is onbekend. in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\index.php on line
>   3
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Host is onbekend. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\index.php on line 3 Failed to connect to
>   MySQL: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host is onbekend.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("axelerate.be.mysql","axelerate_be","*******","axelerate_be");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        echo "it works!";
    }
?>
```

My question:

How can i make this connection work without edditing any config files? (so if there is something to do, I want only to write in the php file)

Thanks!

Comment: I think your host is wrong. ".mysql" is not a valid toplevel-domain. However, axelerate.be seems to be reachable, may try that instead of axelerate.be.mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .mysql based hosts are internal hosts within the one.com network that resolves to the server that hosts your database. These hosts are not meant for connections outside of one.com hosting, and probably doesn't accept connections from the world if they're even available on a public IP.

Comment: I understand why they wouldn't allow it, but is there a way to read content from the database on one.com with my raspberry pi? (maybe in the worst case make a subdomain on axelerate.be that handles the connection and stuff?)

Comment: @Onovar The usual solution is to expose a small web service that makes the needed information available. Depending on what's available, an ssh-tunnel would also work, but I don't think (.. hope) one.com allows SSH connections to their web servers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the host (`axelerate.be.mysql`) exists, try to ping it. AS i can see it doesnt exist.

Comment: ping response doesn't mean that the mysql server is up and running.

Comment: @Azrael But a Ping no response means that the host doesnt exist ! and thats the issue hier.

Comment: @Azrael Actually, no response to a ping usually means that the server is filtering `ICMP` packets. ping does however usually tell you if a DNS lookup failed instead, which is what is of interest here. `nslookup` and `host` might be better suited for host lookups, tho.

Comment: I think your best guess would be using a program which checks if the desired host has port 3306 open (or whatever port is used by the database you are trying to connect)

Answer (score 0):

One.com doesn't support mysqli. You have to use

> $db=mysql_connect("example.com.mysql", "username", "password");
>
> mysql_select_db("database", $db);

Comment: myql_* is deprecated, you should not use this functions anymore.

Comment: Kinda have to use it if mySQLi isn't installed on the server. A quick look at the host's features and FAQ will reveal mySQLi isn't installed.